# Why does adding an Error() method change program behavior in Go?

Tags: go

The program below prints "2.5"

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type myFloat64 float64

// func (f myFloat64) Error() string {
//     return fmt.Sprintf("Error with %v", f)
// }

func main() {
    var a myFloat64 = myFloat64(2.5)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", a)
}
```

Interestingly, when I uncomment the `Error()` method, the program no longer prints "2.5"

**Question:**
Why does adding an `Error()` method change program behavior? Pointers to the Go language specification explaining this behavior would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is how the `fmt` package is implemented. If the printed value implements `error`, its `Error()` method is called.

Comment: I started on an answer that would be at least partly redundant (hence the closed question) but look at [this version on the Go playground](https://go.dev/play/).  Note that I changed the `fmt.Sprintf` to use `%f`; if you leave `%v` in here and run this, you'll see the infinite recursion.

Comment: Because %v calls Error which again uses %v to format the value which calls Error whic hagain formats the value with %v which again calls Error .... You got a infinite loop which produces a SO.

Comment: I kinda think this question should be opened for other people asking the same question. The answer, OP, is because when you add the Error method to your float, you're creating an error type. You can see the spec here: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Errors Then, when you call Printf, the code calls that method during printing, defined here: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.5:src/fmt/print.go;l=620;drc=refs%2Ftags%2Fgo1.17.5

Comment: You can avoid the infinite recursion by converting f first: `return fmt.Sprintf("Error with %v", float64(f))`

Comment: @Jorge, yes, your trick works, but the main problem is %v. This is a handy tool to format a thing you do not know what it is. But if you know what it is: Use an appropriate verb for your type.

Comment: I wish the Go playground told users about stack overflows. Debugging would've been easier.

Answer (score 5):

`myFloat64` implements the `error` interface:

```golang
type error interface {
  Error() string
}
```

`fmt.Println()` will consider `a` as an `error` value, and print the error message by calling `a.Error()`, which executes `fmt.Sprintf("Error with %v", f)`. But `Sprintf` behaves just like `Println`, it also considers `f` as an `error` value and calls `Error()`. This recursion goes infinitely and causes stack overflow.

Comment: Error interface defined here: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Errors